# Drop down list filter web part in Sharepoint is not getting exported

Tags: sharepoint, designer

I would like to implement filtering on my sharepoint list. My list is having title and description columns and I would like to poulate the ASP.NET dropdown list control with titles and when I select the title I would like to show the description. I have followed the link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc300163(office.12).aspx to implement this.

I have created a blank aspx page in Sharepoint Designer and followed the same steps. everything works fine but when I export the webpart, only description part is getting exported. I cannot see the drop down on the page (but when I preview it on the browser I can see both).

Comment: Just a couple of suggestions: 1. remove the word URGENT from the title and 2. edit the title so it is a question.

Answer (score 0):

In your question you say that you are creating a aspx page and then exporting a webpart.

It could be that you are placing the drop down on one thing and exporting another.

Comment: As per the link i have given in my question, the asp.net control should be placed outside the web part zone. With that i am having problem exporting the dropdown control. I tried placing it inside the zone as per your suggestion then data is not getting filtered based on the selection.